# Reading from JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is my JSON array:

```
msg={"userid":"82","0":"82","first":"A","1":"A","last":"B","2":"B","email":"w@w.com","3":"w@w.com","username":"n","4":"n","password":"o","5":"o","hash":"3242","6":"3242","active":"0","7":"0","date":"0","8":"0","holding":"","9":"","ip":"0","10":"0","attempts":"0","11":"0"}
```

now I am trying to get the different parts but nothing I try works. I have tried

```
msg.first //returns undefined
msg['first'] // returns undefined
msg[0] // returns that first bracket {
```

I am sure this can be easily solved, I just dont know what the issue is. This array is output by some php using `json_encode()`. If that code is relavent please let me know and I will put it up.  Thanks.

Comment: Seems to work fine here if your data is actually in the javascript variable as you've shown: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/HxwXr/

Comment: FYI, the code shown in your answer is not an array or JSON - it is a javascript literal object declaration.  JSON is a text format for exchanging structured data in text form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `msg[0]` returns the first bracket, your JSON is somehow being interpreted as a string. This can be easily fixed through jQuery's `parseJSON()`:

```
msg = $.parseJSON(msg);
```

Comment: +1. Note though that (a) all JSON is a string (the code shown in the question is an object literal, not JSON, and not an array), and (b) if the JSON is retrieved via an Ajax request then jQuery's ajax methods will automatically parse the returned JSON and supply the resulting object to the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function display(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key,value) {
        $('#userDetails').append('<li>' + key +  " : " +'<span class="ui-li-aside">'+ value +'</span></li>');
    });
}
        $(document).ready(function() {
            msg= {"userid":"82",
                   "0":"82",
                   "first":"A",
                   "1":"A",
                   "last":"B",
                   "2":"B",
                   "email":"w@w.com",
                   "3":"w@w.com",
                   "username":"n",
                   "4":"n",
                   "password":"o",
                   "5":"o",
                   "hash":"3242",
                   "6":"3242",
                   "active":"0",
                   "7":"0",
                   "date":"0",
                   "8":"0",
                   "holding":"",
                   "9":"",
                   "ip":"0",
                   "10":"0",
                   "attempts":"0",
                   "11":"0"}

        display(msg);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="userDetails"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem a bunch when using the jQuery `ajax` function. You need to specify that you're expecting a json response.

If you make this call, the `data` variable returned will be a string.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/controller/function',
    data: {
        'parameter_name' : value,
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.blah); // Undefined
    },
});
```

But if you specify the `dataType` as "json," the data variable will be a json object.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json", // Have to include this
    type: "POST",
    url: '/controller/function',
    data: {
        'parameter_name' : value,
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.blah); // Defined!!!
    },
});
```

Comment: If the `/controller/function` page returns a response with "Content-type: application/json" then `$.ajax` should parse it automatically.